# Fetching user data using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, angularjs-ng-click

Here is the list of users. I need to display particular user details when clicked on him.

```
<head>
  <script>
    (function() {
      angular.module("testApp", ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.userData = undefined;
        $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30&nat=US').then(function(response) {
          $scope.userData = response.data;
        });
      }]);
    }());
  </script>

  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <h1> PERSONS</h1>

    <form name="commonForm">
      <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="user in userData.results" ng-class="{active : isSelected(user)} style="margin-top:50px;">
        <img class="col-sm-4" ng-src="{{user.picture.large}}"/>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div ><a ng-click="clickMe(p)" class="clickable"><b>{{user.name.first}} {{user.name.last}}</b></a></div>
          <div>{{user.email}}</div>
          <div>{{user.location.street}},{{user.location.city}},{{user.location.state}},{{user.location.postcode}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>   

  </div>
</body>
```

Also check the following link for the demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/J70FKDpdXUtg1AfiVkcz?p=preview

I need to display a particular user's data when we click on the user.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example for the same

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      angular.module("testApp", ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.userData = undefined;
        $scope.selectedUser = undefined;
        $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30&nat=US').then(function(response) {
          $scope.userData = response.data;
        });
        $scope.selectUser = function(usr){
          $scope.selectedUser=usr;
        };
      }]);


    }());
  </script>
  <style>
    .userInfo{
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-top:10px;
      padding:5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .userInfo:hover{
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    .profile{
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .ellipsis{
      white-space: nowrap; 
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <form name="commonForm">
      <div ng-hide="selectedUser">
        <div class="col-sm-4 userInfo" ng-repeat="user in userData.results" ng-click="selectUser(user)" >
            <img class="col-sm-4 profile" ng-src="{{user.picture.medium}}"/>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="ellipsis"><b>{{user.name.first}} {{user.name.last}}</b></div>
                <div class="ellipsis">{{user.email}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div ng-show="selectedUser">
        <button ng-click="selectedUser = undefined">Go Back</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <img class="col-sm-4 profile" ng-src="{{selectedUser.picture.large}}"/>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first" ng-model="selectedUser.name.first">
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last" ng-model="selectedUser.name.last">
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Login:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="selectedUser.login.username" disabled>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="selectedUser.email">
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" ng-model="selectedUser.dob">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nat">Nationality:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nat" ng-model="selectedUser.nat">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```